# Apple ID Password requirements

Tags: icloud, apple-id, password

As you know, the Apple ID Password must meet some minimum requirements, such as having at least one lower case letter, one capital letter, one number, etc.

So, how come sometimes I see a customer putting in a password just 4 characters long?

I am thinking probably if it is a very old password, never changed before, it can be still used as a valid Apple ID Password? Or what?

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of passwords, the **device** passcode and the **appleid** password.

The device passcode gives you access to unlock the device, and it can be as short as a 4 digit PIN.

The AppleID password must be 9 (I think. It's either says "8" or "more than 8") or more characters long, contain at least one capital, one lowercase, and use at least one number or special character.

Answer (score -1):

It's most likely the case that they have a very old Apple ID and haven't changed their passwords since creating their account. I don't know if Apple had lower password requirements in the early days of iTunes/Apple ID, [right now they require 8 character passwords as a minimum it seems.](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4232)